# Bluetooth doesn't work after macOS Mojave update

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mojave, bluetooth

I'm new here. Will someone help me to fix this? I updated my Mac to macOS Mojave and now it cannot connect with Bluetooth devices. Why is this happening and how can I fix this?

it's a MacBook Pro and I tried to connect my wireless headphone. I do not remember the brand.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :) I know it can be frustrating when you're attempting to get something accomplished or to solve an issue, however it's vital that you provide us with sufficient details to assist you. As the question is written, it's lacking the details we need in order to really help you. Can you please [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/365234/edit) your question to include details of the Bluetooth devices you're trying to use. Also, what have you already tried to fix this (e.g. have you tried to pair your devices again, etc)?

Comment: If you can provide more information about your Mac's specifications, that could be useful.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

I tried all available methods.

1. Deleting files from:

   - /Library/Preferences - com.apple.Bluetooth.plist
   - ~/Library/Preferences/ByHost - com.apple.Bluetooth.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
   - and after reboot
2. To reset your Mac’s Bluetooth module
3. Tried through safe mode.
4. Created a new user.
5. Turned off the wifi
6. Made a clean install.
7. Install Catalina
8. Return from backup 10.14.5
9. After replacing the bluetooth board.

** Now everything works! **

Answer (score 0):

Try booting the Mac into safe mode.

> [Safe mode (sometimes called safe boot)](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262) is a way to start up your Mac
>   so that it performs certain checks and prevents some software from
>   automatically loading or opening.
>
> 1. Start or restart your Mac, then immediately press and hold the Shift key. The Apple logo appears on your display. If you don't see
>      the Apple logo, learn what to do.
> 2. Release the Shift key when you see the login window. If your startup disk is encrypted with FileVault, you might be asked to log in
>      twice: once to unlock the startup disk, and again to log in to the
>      Finder.

Test to see if Bluetooth can connect while in safe mode. If it can, restart your Mac without pressing any keys during startup for the regular boot.

If you are still having issues connecting, make a new user account (with admin privileges) and see if the problem exists on that account.

If it exists on the other user account then you may need to [reinstall MacOS Mojave](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/reinstall-macos-mchlp1599/mac).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I'll try it.