# How do I fix bluetooth audio to amp after upgrade to Mojave

Tags: audio, mojave, bluetooth

After upgrading to Mojave, my bluetooth amp now plays at a slower tempo and at a lower pitch with some audio glitches.

How can I fix this?

Bluetooth amp: GraceDigital GDI-BTAR513

Reason for upgrading to Mojave: I upgraded to Mojave to fix an unrelated problem with kernel panics after working with Apple support and the usual PRAM/SMC/Disk First Aid did not solve the problem.

Also tested: JBL stereo headset (successfully!)

Comment: If the JBL headset works then it doesn't appear to be the Mac.  Have you contacted the GraceDigital company support?

Comment: Sure, and I have done that.

Comment: I think, in light of no additional info, that the problem is with the the amp.  That device was released in 2014 and Mojave in 2018 so it could be a problem with how their implementing BT.  Try the answers in [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/365234/88313) to see if that helps.